# Newbie stuck with easy "while" repetition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

The point of the program is to ask the user's name (automatically capitalizing the first letter).

It will then ask for age and gender. If age is over 130 or negative, it will throw an error

The program is supposed to print out all the information, but I can't figure out the while loop condition. Can anyone help me figure out the while loop condition?

-edit- Though the Pastebin's link was edited out, but I think there's important information there. So, I would still give you the link:
http://pastebin.com/UBbXDGSt

```
name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize()
age = int(input("How old are you "))
gender = input("From what gender are you? ").capitalize()

while #I guess I should write something behind the "while" function. But what?
    if age >= 130:
        print("It's impossible that you're that old. Please try again!")
    elif age <= 0:
        print('''It should be logical that ages are written in positive numbers! Well, try again! =)''')

age = int(input("How old are you? "))   

print("Your name is ",name, ". You are ", age, "years old." "\nYou are ", gender, ".")
```

Comment: What makes you think a loop is needed here, and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: You don't need a while loop.  An if statement should suffice.

Comment: I think the goal is to ask the user for their age **while** they've entered an invalid value, until they enter something valid.

Comment: Hello @user1780169 and welcome to Stack Overflow! I've taken the liberty of editing your question. In the future please include your question directly in the text here, not on another website as comments. Also please try to keep introductions short.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a flag that's set off/on if there was a valid input. That will solve the problem of your `while` loop

```
 name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize()
 gender = input("From what gender are you? ").capitalize()
 ok = False #flag
 while not ok:
    age = int(input("How old are you "))
    if age >= 130:
       print("It's impossible that you're that old. Please try again!")
    elif age <= 0:
       print('''It should be logical that ages are written in positive numbers! Well, try again! =)''')
    else:
       ok = True
 print("Your name is ",name, ". You are ", age, "years old." "\nYou are ", gender, ".")
```

Comment: Replace your while condition with either `while (ok is False)` or `while  not ok`.

Comment: Well, it works.. kind of. But.. here's what I get: http://pastebin.com/Rrmg4ZY1 . So it will start all over. But what if I wanted it to ask the age again. And if it gets the correct age, then it will just start print out all the stuff.

Comment: Then only ask the age again @user1780169

Answer (score 0):

Usually here you use `while True`.

```
while True:
    age = int(input("How old are you? "))

    if age >= 130:
        print("It's impossible that you're that old. Please try again!")
    elif age <= 0:
        print('''It should be logical that ages are written in positive numbers! Well, try again! =)''')
    else:
        break
```

This will repeat the question until it gets an acceptable answer, in which case the `break` will break out of the loop.

For completeness you should also check that they entered anything, and that they entered a number. Here I'll also use `continue`, which will restart the loop from the start, ignoring the rest of the code. This makes for a good example:

```
while True:
    age = input("How old are you? ")
    if not age:
        print("Please enter your age.")
        continue
    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please use numbers.")
        continue

    if age >= 130:
        print("It's impossible that you're that old. Please try again!")
    elif age <= 0:
        print('''It should be logical that ages are written in positive numbers! Well, try again! =)''')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: So here's my code so far:

http://pastebin.com/des9qFiL (sorry, I'm having trouble copying the code to my post. This forum doesn't seem to be a usual forum with usual formatting. I will take the time to learn the formatting. But for now, here's the link.)

But the thing is that it won't accept any gender value I've preentered. For example if I enter 'male', it will ask my gender again.

Comment: @user1780169: That is a different problem, and hence a different question. But the logic you use is completely wrong. Programming languages are not natural languages.